# How can I add a user to login as a user and not as a root Yocto project sama5d27 board

Tags: user-interface, authentication, embedded-linux, yocto

I am using **sama5d27 som1 ek1** board and I build a Linux kernel for it using **yocto project**. I open minicom and the system boot. I want to **remove debug tweaks** from my image features but I must now set a **user** to my board to **login** and stop login as a root. How can I add a user to my board ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use one of the useradd classes. The documentation is there:
https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/ref-manual/classes.html#useradd

The `meta-skeleton/recipes-skeleton/useradd/useradd-example.bb` recipe show you how to do that dynamically.

You can also provide the uids and gids statically by using `USERADDEXTENSION = "useradd-staticids"` in local.conf or, preferably in your distro and then having `files/passwd` and `files/group` anywhere in your `BBPATH`.